# Elasticsearch generate suggestion fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I've been reading in to the suggestion in elasticsearch in blogs like: https://www.elastic.co/blog/you-complete-me

But there you have to put in the `name_suggest` data your self, isn't there  a way to automaticly add the data to the `name_suggest` when you map the object.

so update this mapping:

```
curl -X PUT localhost:9200/hotels -d '
{
  "mappings": {
    "hotel" : {
      "properties" : {
        "name" : { "type" : "string" },
        "city" : { "type" : "string" },
        "name_suggest" : {
          "type" :     "completion"
        }
      } 
    }
  }
}'
```

and with these puts:

```
curl -X PUT localhost:9200/hotels/hotel/1 -d '
{
  "name" :         "Mercure Hotel Munich",
  "city" :         "Munich",
  "name_suggest" : "Mercure Hotel Munich"
}'
curl -X PUT localhost:9200/hotels/hotel/2 -d '
{
  "name" :         "Hotel Monaco",
  "city" :         "Munich",
  "name_suggest" : "Hotel Monaco"
}'
curl -X PUT localhost:9200/hotels/hotel/3 -d '
{
  "name" :         "Courtyard by Marriot Munich City",
  "city" :         "Munich",
  "name_suggest" : "Courtyard by Marriot Munich City"
}'
```

so we can lose the `name_suggest` field.

So the ultimate goal is when you start typing `Ho` the first result would be `Hotel`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [ngrams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenfilter.html) if you want partial matches within words, or [edge ngrams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html) if you just want to match from the beginning of words.

Here's an example. I set up an index like this:

```
PUT /test_index
{
    "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "edge_ngram_filter": {
               "type": "edge_ngram",
               "min_gram": 2,
               "max_gram": 20
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "edge_ngram_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "edge_ngram_filter"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
       "doc": {
           "properties": {
               "name": {
                   "type": "string",
                   "index_analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer",
                   "search_analyzer": "standard"
               },
               "city": {
                   "type": "string"
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Then added your docs:

```
POST /test_index/doc/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"name":"Mercure Hotel Munich","city":"Munich"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"name":"Hotel Monaco","city":"Munich"}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"name":"Courtyard by Marriot Munich City","city":"Munich"}
```

Now I can query for documents with `"hot"` in the name like this:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "name": "hot"
        }
    }
}
```

and I get back the correct docs:

```
{
   "took": 41,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0.625,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.625,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Hotel Monaco",
               "city": "Munich"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.5,
            "_source": {
               "name": "Mercure Hotel Munich",
               "city": "Munich"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

There are various ways this can be tweaked or generalized. For example, you can apply the ngram analyzer to the [_all](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html) field if you want to match on more than one field.

Here is the code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/3583de02c4f7d33e07ba4c2def9badf90692a290

Comment: Hi, I don't want the full results as answer, i Just wanted the word `Hotel` because that exists the most